# Some errors in Swift 2 program

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently in the process of making a GPS app in Swift 2 but I am constantly getting errors for some unknown reason. I am not sure if they changed some new things with updates or I am just doing it wrong. If someone can help me I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Here is the code from ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol HandleMapSearch: class {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var selectedPin: MKPlacemark?
    var resultSearchController: UISearchController!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
        let locationSearchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LocationSearchTable") as! LocationSearchTable
        resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
        resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
        let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.placeholder = "Search for places"
        navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
        resultSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        definesPresentationContext = true
        locationSearchTable.mapView = mapView
        locationSearchTable.handleMapSearchDelegate = self

    }

    func getDirections(){
        guard let selectedPin = selectedPin else { return }
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: selectedPin)
        let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
        mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    }
}

extension ViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else { return }
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("error:: \(error)")
    }

}

extension ViewController: HandleMapSearch {

    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark: MKPlacemark){
        // cache the pin
        selectedPin = placemark
        // clear existing pins
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
        annotation.title = placemark.name

        if let city = placemark.locality,
            let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
            annotation.subtitle = "\(city) \(state)"
        }

        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

}

extension ViewController : MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{

        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }

        let reuseId = "pin"
        guard let pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView else { return nil }

        pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        pinView.canShowCallout = true
        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: smallSquare))
        button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "car"), forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.getDirections), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button

        return pinView
    }
}
```

There will be pictures of all the errors I am getting. Thanks again

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you name your project MapKit?

Comment: yes. did I do something wrong

Comment: Yes, don't give your project the same name as any of Apple's frameworks.  It creates a name clash between the module automatically created for your classes which is given the same name as your project and Apple's MapKit module, which is causing your errors.

Comment: oh ok so if I change the name it should be fine?

Comment: thank you. it actually worked. I feel kind of stupid after knowing the only thing I did wrong was naming it mapKit